# SSL certificate drop down missing in IIS 10

Tags: ssl, iis, binding

I have tried to search for this issue on stack overflow, but most questions are about certificate not available in the drop down.

In this case, the option to choose an SSL certificate does not exist in "Add Bindings" in IIS manager.

[image]

This is how it is supposed to be (based on some google images):

[image]

Any ideas why that option is missing on my IIS manager??

Comment: When did you start face this issue? What about specify https binding via command line or recreate binding host header in applicationhost.config? Could you see server certificate in IIS manger server node? Besides, have you tried to reinstall IIS? ? More details would be appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue by uninstalling and reinstalling IIS.

It is not an easy fix since all my IIS configurations, app pool etc wiped out and I had to redo it again so my advice is to make a note of the setup before you wipe it out.